# Cascading dropdown duped values

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to get the cascading dropdown to work in razor pages and I am scratching my head now, since I need this approach:

Country -> City/Plant (so, classic, entry level task)

the problem is, I am doing something wrong and the list that should populate all cities/plants, does show the correct number of values from the table, but lists only the first value duplicated by the distinct number of requested values

[duplicated values, the count is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvOP3.png)

interface:

```
 public interface ICountry
{
    IEnumerable<getCountries> GetCountries();
    IEnumerable<getCountriesAndPlants> GetPlants(string id);
}

public class CountryService : ICountry
{
    private readonly CContext _context;
    public CountryService(CContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IEnumerable<getCountries> GetCountries()
    {
        IEnumerable<getCountries> countries = _context.GetCountries.ToList();
        return countries;
    }

    public IEnumerable<getCountriesAndPlants> GetPlants(string country)
    {
        IEnumerable<getCountriesAndPlants> plant = _context.GetCountriesAndPlants.Where(plants => plants.Country == country).ToList();
        return plant;
    }
}
```

data

```
 public partial class getCountries
{
    [Key]
    public string Country { get; set; }

}

public partial class getCountriesAndPlants
{
    [Key]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PlantName { get; set; }

}


private readonly ICountry _countryService;
public CreateBudget(ICountry countryService)
    {
        _countryService = countryService;
    }
public JsonResult OnGetPlants(string country)
    {
        return new JsonResult(_countryService.GetPlants(country));
    }
    public IEnumerable<getPlants> getPlants { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<getCountries> getCountries { get; set; }
```

script

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#country").on("change", function () {
                    var country = $(this).val();
                    $("#plt").empty();
                    $("#plt").append("<option value=''>Select Plant</option>");
                    $.getJSON(`?handler=Plants&country=${country}`, (data) => {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            console.log(i);
                            $("#plt").append(`<option value="${item.country}">${item.plantName}</option>`);
                        }); 
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

any help would be highly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Why is your naming so terrible? Classes shouldn't be verbs, you have singular where you should have plural and plural where you should have singular?? Plus you don't show the code that actually matters (e.g. what is `_context.GetCountriesAndPlants`?)

Comment: Can you share your data in `$.each(data`?

Comment: @YiyiYou: yes, it is the same behaviour as in screenshot, picking the top value for the country and multiplied by the count of that country in the table: `0: {country: 'Germany', plantName: 'Falkenhagen'}` (x8)

table:
Country | Plantname
Germany | Falkenhagen
Germany | Hamburg
Germany | Berlin
Germany | Dresden
Germany | Hamburg
Germany | Krefeld
Germany | Lübz
Germany | Satow

Comment: It looks like your data format is correct.Does your console.log(i) print different number?

Comment: @YiyiYou yes, there are other numbers but just the first value from the top of the table is visible
https://i.imgur.com/ewri2Iv.png <- console.log
https://i.imgur.com/Vx0wWmQ.png <- view from ssms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who struggles with this in the future:

The issue I was not aware of was the key in the datamodel. As I started rebuilding the datamodel I saw i had [Key] annotation on a column that was not the primary key in the sql db, so all I had to add was [HasNoKey] annotation in the OnModelCreating:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<CountriesAndPlants>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();
        });
```